# Legacy Direct3D8 app displays rotated image in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, directx

I have a problem trying to get an old (17 years) app working on a new machine running Windows 10.

The app (it is a simple maze game) uses Direct3D 8 and was designed to run in a portrait aspect of 768 x 1024.

When I try the app in a Windows 10 virtual machine (under VMWare Workstation) it works ok. But on the real machine, the image is rotated 90 degrees.

This happens whether we set the screen resolution to 768 x 1024 or 1024 x 768 (i.e. setting the orientation to portrait or landscape makes no difference - the image is always rotated).

[image: Resolution set to 768 x 1024]
[image: Resolution set to 1024 x 768]

Since it doesn't happen in the VM my theory is that it's something to do with the graphics card, maybe misapplying some sort of compatibility setting for old DirectX apps or something?

Does anyone have any suggestions where we could look?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is using DX12 and your app predates Windows 10 by about 10 years.

So the only practical solution here is to run the app in a Virtual Machine.

Virtual Machines work best on a fast machine with a very fast SSD drive to support the VM inside the Host machine.

Also the likelihood is that the next major Windows 10 update will uninstall the app if you leave it installed in the current Windows 10 system.